# gridlines in the chart, how to obtain in this example

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

How to obtain grid lines in the following chart ?   I have been trying to obtain grid lines by using d3noobs d3 tips and tricks. But this code doesn't work

```
       .grid.tick {
            stroke: lightgrey;
opacity: 0.7;
    }
  .grid path {
stroke-width: 0;
 }



        <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>The d3 test</title>
         <style> \\ css
            .chart {

                  }

                 .main text {
font: 10px sans-serif;  
   }

                 .axis line, .axis path {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
stroke: black;
fill: none;
  }

  circle {
fill: steelblue;
   }



        </style>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js">                                 

         </script>
  </head>
  <body>\\ script
    <div class='content'>
      <!-- /the chart goes here -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scatterchart.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and scatterchart.js

```
     var data = [[2,2], [2,5], [6,6], [6,7],[25,25]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60}
  , width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
          .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('body')
.append('svg:svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr('class', 'chart')

var main = chart.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('class', 'main')   

// draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(yAxis);




var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")\\dots
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )\\x pos
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )\\ y pos
      .attr("r", 8); \\ radius
```

Thus how to obtain grid lines in this chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not put the necessary code for the gridlines. This is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FWV65/) with the necessary code. Check the last lines in the code, starting with:

```
main.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));
```

...

Comment: Thank you FernOfTheAndes. Do you know how to flip the chart ? The X-Axis must go to top and the Y-Axis should increase from top to bottom. I could move X-axis to the top but the chart took values for previous format itself.

Comment: Sure, I have flipped the chart on y and moved the x axis up. I put comments in the appropriate places. I am assuming this is what you want, and you can make further improvements by studying the overall code. This is the [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FWV65/1/).

Comment: Yes FernOfAndes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: How to parse var data = [[2,2], [2,5], [6,6], [6,7],[25,25]] from an external file such as .txt or csv ? And how to join various data points with a line ?